# numpy.array not working properly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to convert a list of lists into an array and something weird is happening.

For example, if I declare the list as:

```
a=[]
a.append(['a',1,10,100])
a.append(['b',2,20,200])
a.append(['c',3,30,300])
a.append(['d',4,40,400])
```

and then convert into a vector by

```
a=np.array(a)
```

the end result is

```
[['a','1','1','1'],['b','2','2','2'],['c','3','3','3'],['d','4','4','4']]
```

I'm a total Python beginner, but from what I've read by using np.array everything in the vector is converted into a string (please correct me if I'm wrong). Why are the zeroes being ignored here and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the resulting data type (that numpy had to guess) of the array is "string of length 1". You need to specify a maximum item size:

```
In [51]: np.array(['a', 10])
Out[51]:
array(['a', '1'],
      dtype='|S1')

In [56]: np.array(['a', 10], dtype=(str, 5))
Out[56]:
array(['a', '10'],
      dtype='|S5')

In [57]: np.array(['a', 123456], dtype=(str, 5))
Out[57]:
array(['a', '12345'],
      dtype='|S5')

In [58]: np.array(['a', 123456], dtype=(str, 6))
Out[58]:
array(['a', '123456'],
      dtype='|S6')
```

[Numpy data types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#data-type-objects-dtype)

Are you sure your 2d array shouldn't be a 1d array of records (see askewchan's answer)?

Comment: Actually this is open for some changes, but better just give the correct string length when non-strings are involved

Comment: I need the 2d, but this took care of the problem perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you realize that [these are the only things you can do with strings](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html).

Comment: @user1876307 Do you really want strings?

Answer (score 5):

Since your array(s) have non-uniform data type, you must specify a "structured" `dtype`

```
In [2]: a = [('a', 1, 10, 100),
   ...:      ('b', 2, 20, 200),
   ...:      ('c', 3, 30, 300),
   ...:      ('d', 4, 40, 400)]

In [3]: a = np.array(a, dtype = "S1, int, int, int")

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([('a', 1, 10, 100),
       ('b', 2, 20, 200),
       ('c', 3, 30, 300),
       ('d', 4, 40, 400)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S1'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8')])
```

Which you can access easily as:

```
In [5]: a.dtype.names = ['name','x','y','z']

In [6]: a['x']
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [7]: a['name']
Out[7]: 
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [8]: a[0]
Out[8]: ('a', 1, 10, 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `np.array` does not convert everything to string. [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) Says:

"dtype : data-type, optional
The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array."

In general using numpy you should not mix types. In your example you do. My guess would be, numpy tried to guess the correct type for your arguments, which resulted in up-casting to something string-like. But it did go wrong. I am not experienced with numpy enough to say exactly what happened. So maybe someone smarter will address this. I'd suggest [numpy.dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) for futher reading. You can do some magic with it.

What I do suggest is to stick to one type when you create `numpy.array`. Especially as it is designed to perform computations, while you tried to sneak in some strings/characters. I am not sure what computations you want to do.

Edit:
Yea, I guess I'm a numpy noob. Structured dtype seems to be the perfect way for mixed types arrays.